# Understanding Perl's `eval`

Tags: perl

I am trying to understand Perl's `eval` function.
Here is a test script I wrote:

```
[red@tools-dev1 ~]$ cat evaltest.pl 
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($arg1, $arg2, $op ) = split /,/;
    my $cmd = "$arg1 $op $arg2";    
    print "$cmd\n"; 
    my $rc = eval { $cmd };
    print "rc is [$rc]\n";
}


__DATA__
1,2,!=
1,1,!=
1,2,=
1,1,=
1,2,==
2,3,>
3,2,>
3,3,>
2,3,>=
3,2,>=
3,3,>=
2,3,<
3,2,<
3,3,<
2,3,<=
3,2,<=
3,3,<=
```

When I execute I get this output ...

```
[red@tools-dev1 ~]$ ./evaltest.pl 
1 != 2
rc is [1 != 2]
1 != 1
rc is [1 != 1]
1 = 2
rc is [1 = 2]
1 = 1
rc is [1 = 1]
1 == 2
rc is [1 == 2]
2 > 3
rc is [2 > 3]
3 > 2
rc is [3 > 2]
3 > 3
rc is [3 > 3]
2 >= 3
rc is [2 >= 3]
3 >= 2
rc is [3 >= 2]
3 >= 3
rc is [3 >= 3]
2 < 3
rc is [2 < 3]
3 < 2
rc is [3 < 2]
3 < 3
rc is [3 < 3]
2 <= 3
rc is [2 <= 3]
3 <= 2
rc is [3 <= 2]
3 <= 3
rc is [3 <= 3]
```

... I was trying to get output that looks more like this:

```
1 != 2
rc is [1]
1 != 1
rc is [0]
1 = 2
rc is [0]
1 = 1
rc is [1]
1 == 2
rc is [0]
2 > 3
rc is [0]
3 > 2
rc is [1]
3 > 3
rc is [0]
2 >= 3
rc is [0]
3 >= 2
rc is [1]
3 >= 3
rc is [1]
2 < 3
rc is [1]
3 < 2
rc is [0]
3 < 3
rc is [0]
2 <= 3
rc is [1]
3 <= 2
rc is [0]
3 <= 3
rc is [1]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two forms of eval, and you are confusing them.  One (`eval BLOCK`) compiles BLOCK when the eval itself is compiled; the only thing it does is catch exceptions and store them in `$@`.  You are looking for `eval STRING`, which compiles and executes the Perl code in the given expression (storing any compile time errors or run time exceptions in `$@`).

So say just `eval $cmd` instead of `eval { $cmd }`.

Also note that the comparison operators return a special Boolean false value that is an empty string in string context but 0 in numeric context, so your output will have `rc is []`, not `rc is [0]`.

When there is a compile error (which will happen for your `1 = 1` and `1 = 2`), eval will return undef (and as I mentioned, place the error in `$@`).

Comment: Doing `eval $cmd` is returning `[]` instead of `[0]` when `false`. Could you tell me why?

Comment: @Oktalist: no, false is a special value, not the empty string.  Compare `use warnings; $x = ""; print $x + 42;` to `use warnings; $x = 0==1; print $x + 42;`

Comment: I was wonder how I can or if I need to use `eq` or `==`? I know that `==` works for numbers and I should use `eq` for strings, but I am not sure how to tell if a scalar is number of a string.

Comment: well, normally you know where the value comes from and whether you expect it to be a just a number or any string.